# Mysql multiple table joins with derived tables

Tags: mysql, self-join

[My Table Details image with test data](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20gfkvt&s=8#.VVD6SpOuHIU)

I have come up with below code:

```
select tableName,userDets,regDate
from (
(SELECT 'Table1' AS tableName, t1.username as userDets, t1.created_date as regDate FROM table1 t1 group by username )
union all
(SELECT 'Table2' AS tableName, t2.username as userDets, t2.created_date as regDate FROM table2 t2 group by username )
union all 
(SELECT 'Table3' AS tableName, t3.username as userDets, t3.created_date as regDate FROM table3 t3 group by username )
) AS allTableCombo 
group by allTableCombo.userDets
```

If in this code i use order by date at last and then make it subquery for another select with group by username , I can obtain required output. But I dont want to use sbuquery.
Please if anyone could provide me with an alternative.. I tried with self join but was not success on using it....

Comment: So, you have no PK on those tables?

Comment: Oh sorry , all table has PK

Comment: alternative would be to create a temp table or table variable and insert into it for all three queries, then select from it.  Not sure on performance differences for your data

Comment: what's wrong with subqueries?  If your result depends on three tables, you have to query all of them.

Comment: subquery may give performance issue while data is large ...so that